# How to block all incoming proxy visits except from one specific I.P?

Tags: proxy, .htaccess, ip, mod-rewrite, regex

I have a page that is prone to attacks, so, in order to reduce the anonymous attacks, I use this code in my **.htaccess** which I found online :

```
# BLOCK PROXY VISITS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA}                 !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED}           !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA}       !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR}     !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION}    !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION}   !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR} !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP}      !^$
 RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

My problem is that one advertiser uses proxies inside his company and thus cannot visit my page. I have no idea on regular expressions, even though I *think* i can recognize one when I see it, as in "*oh, look a regex*". I think the conditions above are regexes, but I do not have the knowledge to alter them in a way, that **only** the proxy visits from this specific static IP are not banned.

How do I achieve that if possible? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line right below `RewriteEngine on`, add these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^12\.34\.56\.78$ 
RewriteRUle ^ - [L]
```

This will allow a remote IP connection from **12.34.56.78** to pass through without being subjected to the proxy checks (which should come afterwards).

Comment: your code doesnt block proxies!
I have private proxies and try to do that and it not block.

Comment: Actually, it blocks anonymous proxies quite well, but elite proxies are able to get past those settings.